# Use level of pandas index as a part of an output file name

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to loop through a data frame using

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   #Do Stuff
```

I have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
                  pt_ID Easting Northing         Attribute
Site  Survey_Date                                         
M006R 2004-12-30   1019  245473   651608  WE              
      2004-12-30   1038  245563   651543  WE              
      2004-12-30   1017  245471   651593  WE              
      2004-12-30   1021  245482   651616  WE              
      2004-12-30   1023  245478   651604  WE              
      2004-12-30   1049  245665   651498  WE              
      2004-12-30   1020  245477   651614  WE              
      2004-12-30   1041  245577   651528  WE              
      2004-12-30   1040  245574   651535  WE              
      2004-12-30   1037  245552   651544  WE
```

As can bee seen I have a multindex using `Site` and `Survey_Date`.  As It loops through the dataframe I would like to use the `Survey_Date` as a part of and output file name and have no idea how to access it as it loops through the data frame.

For example I would like an output filename of:

`outfilename = 'test_' + Survey_Date + '.extention'`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this to get a better idea:

```
for index, row in df.head().iterrows():
    print "Site: {}, Survey_Date {}".format(*index)
```

Essentially, the `index` variable is a tuple with each level of the multiindex.  Access the level you want with `index[0]` for `'Site'` or `index[1]` for `'Survey_Date'`